# Event.observe only works with document and not specific id's?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a page where I am learning prototype js and having a time with the Event.observe.  My problem is this works if I click anywhere on the document:

```
Event.observe(document, 'click', respondToClick);

function respondToClick() {
  alert("Test...");
}
```

But I want to make several Event.observe functions for different id's  so I did this:

```
Event.observe('foo', 'click', respondToClick);

function respondToClick() {
  alert("Test...");
}
```

now foo is just a row that looks like this:

```
<tr id="foo">
                <th>Row Title</th>

                <th>Open/Close</th>
            </tr>
```

But when I click on the row it doesn't proc the alert box.  I have tried too many things and am now asking for help.  Any ideas why specific elements won't generate the alert?

Answer (score 0):

EIther you can try this

```
Event.observe($('foo'), 'click', respondToClick);
```

or

```
 $("foo").observe('click', respondToClick);
```

Reference: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/

See it in action

http://plugins.amiwithyou.com/sof/event.htm

Comment: According to the docs you link to, `Event.observe("foo", "click", respondToClick)` should also work, though. The problem may come from something else.

Comment: Something must be wrong because none of that works...  I read the documentation and did an exact example on my page but it will not work.  But if I call document, it works fine...

Comment: In my case it is working. Please see it in http://plugins.amiwithyou.com/sof/event.htm

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, "foo" is the element id, not the element itself. Therefore, $("foo") or document.getElementById("foo") should work.

Comment: @Hoque, indeed, I was just saying that `Event.observe()` supports an element id as its first argument, according to the documentation.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:Supports element as well as elementID. Thank you so much for clarification.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi,have you tried the link http://plugins.amiwithyou.com/sof/event.htm  . Or do you have any update on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the execution order.

```
Event.observe('foo', 'click', respondToClick);
```

will only work if

```
<tr id="foo">...
```

is already existing in the HTML DOM